# How to change the background of a tkinter.Button through clicking on it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

*Basically I want to call a non-static and non-global function via the* `command = *function parameter*`

---

I want to create a `tkinter.Button` that changes its color when it gets clicked.

I tried to  make a subclass to add additional attributes which have other offtopic advantages:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Cell(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, master, coord , command, bg = "ghost white", state = 0):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, bg = bg, height = height, width = width, relief = relief, bd = bd)
        self.coord = coord
        self.state = state

    def switch(self):
        if self.state:
            self.state = 0
            self.config(bg = "gray1")
        else:
            self.state = 1
            self.config(bg = "ghost white")
```

But in short I would like to do something like this:

```
tk.Button(master, command = lambda: self.config(bg = "color"))
```

Is this possible?

---

***EDIT***:
Further context because I think my explanation didn't quite get the message abroad. And more error messages:

*My basic concept:* I want a rectangular grid where you can click on a cell and the cell changes the color from white to black or the other way around.
Because I had no other idea (not very familiar with Tkinter) I used buttons but if someone has a better idea I would be very interested

*Problems:*

1. If I try to use `self.` I get

   NameError: name 'self' is not defined

in the head of the function - without calling it. So that won't work.

2. I could just do

   cell = tk.Button(master, command = cell.switch)

But I have very many buttons and I store them in an array

```
board = []
for i in range(x):
    row = []
    for j in range(y):
        # Button or selfmade Cell class - no difference
        cell = tk.Button(master, command = 'needed')
        row.append(cell)
    board.append(row)
```

is my setup

I tried the following options:

1. `command = board[x][y].switch`
   raises an *Index Error*. Presumably, because the index doesn't exist in the moment of declaration

   - with `lambda: board[x][y].switch`: I get no Error but nothing happens on clicking
   - with `lambda: board[x][y].switch()`: I get no Error but it only calls switch on the last cell added into the array
2. `command = lambda: board[x][y].config(bg = "grey1")` - works fine but every button only changes the colour of the *last button added into* `board`

Comment: Have you tried it to see what would happen?

Comment: @BryanOakley further detailed in my edit

Comment: Hi @Proxycon, have you solved your problem? did you see the edit to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you should be calling in the lambda the switch() function

```
tk.Button(master, command = lambda: self.switch())
```

But I think you can play more with this, for instance, you can add an optional arg of the color:

```
def switch(self, *args):
  if args:
     self.state = args['state']
     self.config(bg = args['bg'])
  else:
      if self.state:
          self.state = 0
          self.config(bg = "gray1")
      else:
          self.state = 1
          self.config(bg = "ghost white")
```

l have done things like this before but I don't have the project now...

**Edit:**

I just saw your edit and I think I can help you...

Try making the switch function a `@staticmethod` so you don't need `self`.

To do that you'll need to pass the `state` and if you want you can add `*args` as shown above...

Don't forget you can always give `command` a default value, then after declaring the object change it.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you but the use of `self` in the command attribute raises an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lambda method to change the colour of the button if it is clicked.

This simple example shows the principle

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root,text="click me", command = lambda: btn.config(bg="green"))
btn.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Providing that changing the colour of the button is all that you want to do this works ok.

If you want it to do something else as well as change colour, then try something like this which, as you suggested, creates a new class that inherits the tk.Button behaviour, but also changed colour when clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class SpecialButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        self.clicked_color = kw.pop('clickedbg','green')
        tk.Button.__init__(self,master,**kw)
        self.bind('<Button-1>',self.clicked)
    def clicked(self,*args):
        self['bg'] = self.clicked_color

def somethingElse():
    print("Doing something else")

btn = tk.Button(root,text="click me", command = lambda: btn.config(bg="green"))
btn.grid()
btn2 = SpecialButton(root,text="You can click me too", command=somethingElse, clickedbg='red')
btn2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

I've added a new keyword for this button `clickedbg` which you can use to configure which color the button should change to.

Comment: Thank you but i can't even get the button to call a non-global and non_static funktion. What to do after that is not the problem. I explained further in the edit of my question